# Using R to "click" download a .csv file from a webpage

Tags: r, post

When I click the download button on this [page](https://www.m-x.ca/en/trading/data/historical?symbol=CRA&from=2023-03-16&to=2023-03-16#CRAH23-20230316) using the parameters:

- Futures
- Select: CRA
- From: 2023-03-16
- To: 2023-03-16

I get a csv file in my downloads folder.
I'd like to use R to get this as a dataframe.

Based on the answer from @Russ I have tried to use RSelenium to download the file. Still no luck.

```
# Load library ---------------------------------------------------------------
library("RSelenium")
library("tidyverse")

# The URL changes depending on what parameters are chosen
# So we don't have to use RSelenium to set parameters!
# It can be done with the URL

# Choose values------------------------------------------------------------

transaction_type <- "Futures"
symbol <- "CRA"
start_date <- "2023-03-16"
end_date <- "2023-03-16"


url <- paste0("https://www.m-x.ca/en/trading/data/historical?symbol=",
              symbol,
              "&from=",
              start_date,
              "&to=",
              end_date)


# I think this bit just specifies where on the page we start, so probably not
# needed:     #CRAH23-20230316


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------


# set up RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------
file_path <- getwd() |> str_replace_all("/", "\\\\\\\\")
fprof <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = file_path,
                                 browser.download.folderList = 2L,
                                 browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = FALSE,
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile = "text/csv",
                                 browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk = "text/csv")
)
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = fprof, port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)


# Click on the download button -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$findElements("id", "btnDnld")[[1]]$clickElement()

remDr$close()
```

---

Original Question

The no RSelenium code I've tried downloads the whole HTML page, not just the csv file.

```
library(httr)

POST("https://www.m-x.ca/en/trading/data/historical?symbol=CRA&from=2023-03-16&to=2023-03-16#CRAH23-20230316",
     body = list(`frmHisto[]` = "Futures", 
                 `symbol[]` = "CRA",
                 `from[]` = "2023-03-16",
                 `to[]` = "2023-03-16"), 
     encode = "form",
     write_disk("quote_CRA_20230316.csv")) -> res
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use RSelenium for this?

Comment: I wondered whether it was possible to do this without using RSelenium. Are you saying that because the URL is not displayed when right-clicking that I must use RSelenium?

Comment: I don't know that it's a must, but I think it'd be possible with RSelenium! The button is tricky because I think there's some javascript behind the scenes that has to be called to actually complete the download. I'll share an RSelenium solution, but there may be other ways to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/27243/how-to-find-out-the-real-download-url-on-download-sites-that-use-redirects), I saw how to see an example of the actual download URL in Chrome.

```
When you've started the transfer in Firefox, cancel it, and right click the download and hit "Copy download link". If you're using an older version, right click it and click on "Properties", and the link will be in the window which opens.

In Chrome - run download as normal - then go to Menu - Downloads - and you should see the direct link which was used. Or press Ctrl + J to open the window.
```

Now my original no RSelenium solution works fine.

```
library(httr)

POST("https://www.m-x.ca/en/trading/data/historical?symbol=CRA&from=2023-03-16&to=2023-03-16&dnld=1#quotes",
     body = list(`frmHisto[]` = "Futures", 
                 `symbol[]` = "CRA",
                 `from[]` = "2023-03-16",
                 `to[]` = "2023-03-16"), 
     encode = "form",
     write_disk("quote_CRA_20230316.csv")) -> res
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about post, but here's an `RSelenium` way to download the file:

```
# Load library ---------------------------------------------------------------
library(RSelenium)


# The URL changes depending on what parameters are chosen
# So we don't have to use RSelenium to set parameters!
# It can be done with the URL

# Choose values------------------------------------------------------------

transaction_type <- "Futures"
symbol <- "CRA"
start_date <- "2023-03-16"
end_date <- "2023-03-16"


url <- paste0("https://www.m-x.ca/en/trading/data/historical?symbol=",
              symbol,
              "&from=",
              start_date,
              "&to=",
              end_date)


# I think this bit just specifies where on the page we start, so probably not
# needed:     #CRAH23-20230316


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------


# set up RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4547L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)


# Click on the download button -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$findElements("id", "btnDnld")[[1]]$clickElement()
```

Comment: I tried this. Where is the downloaded file supposed to be? The one difference is that I started RSelenium like this: remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

Comment: If it worked, it should go to your default download location.

Comment: I assume that's the root of the project directory shown by getwd(). No file found ;-(

Comment: It's the default download location for your web browser, which most likely isn't the project's working directory. If you're using windows you can find the default download location by running this command in R: ```system2("powershell", args = "(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path", stderr = TRUE)```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default is my home directory. No files there. Then, I tried explicitly defining the download directory. Still no luck. See original question.